# how To give an ID to an element created with innerHTML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I created a parent div in html and created an array of objects that contains infos about the child Divs, and because there is a lot of songs I can't create all of theme in HTML, what I want is when I click a song the infos in the object get added to the player what I'm thinking of is some how create a loop that gives IDs to each objects of the songs so that I can create I loop that get's the ID of the clicked  elements and get the right infos.

This is my Code :

```js
const playlistSongs = document.querySelector(".playlist-songs");
const btns = document.querySelector('.song-details');
const playingNow = document.querySelector('.song-p-now');

const goodVibesPlaylist = [{
    img: 'img/2.jpg',
    idd: 1,
    songName: 'Am I Wrong',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Am-I-wrong.mp3'),
    artist: 'Nico & Vinz',
  },
  {
    img: 'img/3.jpg',
    idd: 2,
    songName: 'Sex,Drugs,Etc',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Sex-Drugs-Etc.mp3'),
    artist: 'Beach Weather',

  },


  {
    img: 'img/7.jpg',
    idd: 3,
    songName: 'Me Myself & I ',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Me-Myself-I.mp3'),
    artist: 'G-easy',

  },

  {
    img: 'img/4.jpg',
    idd: 4,
    songName: 'Blood In The Water',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Blood-In-The-Water.mp3'),
    artist: 'grandson',
  },

  {
    img: 'img/5.jpg',
    idd: 5,
    songName: 'Eastside',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Eastside.mp3'),
    artist: 'Benny Blanco',
  },

  {
    img: 'img/6.jpg',
    idd: 6,
    songName: 'Everything Black ',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Everything-Black.mp3'),
    artist: 'Unlike Puto',

  }
]

// That's How I add the songs 

let songsHTML = '';

const elemt = document.createAttribute

for (let song of goodVibesPlaylist) {
  const html = `
   <div class="song-details" id="${song.idd}"> //here how I tried to give IDs
    <div class="song-num " >${song.idd}</div>
    <div class="song-poster"><img src=${song.img} alt=""></div>
    <div class="song-artist-name">
        <div class="song-name">${song.songName}</div>
        <div class="artist-name">N${song.artist}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="play-btn"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
        play_arrow
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>`;

  songsHTML += html;
  console.log(btns.id)
}

document.querySelector('#addTo')
  .innerHTML = songsHTML;


// This is the eventListnner loop


for (let song of btns) {

  playingNow.innerHTML = ` <div class="song-poster"><img src="img/7.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="song-artist-name">
    <div class="song-name">Me,Myself & I</div>
    <div class="artist-name">G-easy</div>
</div>`

}
```

```html
<div class="playlist-songs" id="addTo"></div>

<div class="song-p-now">
  <div class="song-poster"><img src="img/7.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="song-artist-name">
    <div class="song-name">Me,Myself & I</div>
    <div class="artist-name">G-easy</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const goodVibesPlaylist = [{
    img: 'img/2.jpg',
    idd: 1,
    songName: 'Am I Wrong',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Am-I-wrong.mp3'),
    artist: 'Nico & Vinz',
  },
  {
    img: 'img/3.jpg',
    idd: 2,
    songName: 'Sex,Drugs,Etc',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Sex-Drugs-Etc.mp3'),
    artist: 'Beach Weather',

  },


  {
    img: 'img/7.jpg',
    idd: 3,
    songName: 'Me Myself & I ',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Me-Myself-I.mp3'),
    artist: 'G-easy',

  },

  {
    img: 'img/4.jpg',
    idd: 4,
    songName: 'Blood In The Water',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Blood-In-The-Water.mp3'),
    artist: 'grandson',
  },

  {
    img: 'img/5.jpg',
    idd: 5,
    songName: 'Eastside',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Eastside.mp3'),
    artist: 'Benny Blanco',
  },

  {
    img: 'img/6.jpg',
    idd: 6,
    songName: 'Everything Black ',
    audio: new Audio('audio/Everything-Black.mp3'),
    artist: 'Unlike Puto',

  }
]

// That's How I add the songs 

let songsHTML = '';

const elemt = document.createAttribute
// this is the loop that creates those elements 
// put the elements after this loop
for (let song of goodVibesPlaylist) {
  const html = `
   <div class="song-details" id="${song.idd}"> 
    <div class="song-num " >${song.idd}</div>
    <div class="song-poster"><img src=${song.img} alt=""></div>
    <div class="song-artist-name">
        <div class="song-name">${song.songName}</div>
        <div class="artist-name">N${song.artist}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="play-btn"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
        play_arrow
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>`;

  songsHTML += html;
}

document.querySelector('#addTo')
  .innerHTML = songsHTML;


// This is the eventListnner loop

// at this posint these elements have been created , you can access them now
    const playlistSongs = document.querySelectorAll(".playlist-songs");
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.song-details');
    const playingNow = document.querySelectorAll('.song-p-now');

for (let song of btns) {

  playingNow.innerHTML = ` <div class="song-poster"><img src="img/7.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="song-artist-name">
    <div class="song-name">Me,Myself & I</div>
    <div class="artist-name">G-easy</div>
</div>`

}
```

```html
  <div class="song-p-now">
    <div class="song-poster"><img src="img/7.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="song-artist-name">
      <div class="song-name">Me,Myself & I</div>
      <div class="artist-name">G-easy</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

your code is fine,

the problem is you are trying to access these elements before they are created,

```
const playlistSongs = document.querySelector(".playlist-songs");
const btns = document.querySelector('.song-details');
const playingNow = document.querySelector('.song-p-now');
```

open your devtools and console log `btns`
you will see its `null`, this is becase when you call `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` for an element that does not exist, you will get null,

so in your code when you said `console.log(btns.id)` you are basicly saying `console.log(null.id)` this will throw an error bacause the `null` object does not have an `id` value

***solution***

```
const playlistSongs = document.querySelector(".playlist-songs");
const btns = document.querySelector('.song-details');
const playingNow = document.querySelector('.song-p-now');
```

put these elements after the for loop that creates them, and use `querySelectorAll` not `querySelector`, `querySelector` will just get the first element it finds with that class

i have made the canges, see the comments in the code

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting the div by `const btns = document.querySelector('.song-details');`. At that point. No div with class "song-details" exists. What you are doing is you selecting an element before it is even created. I believe this might fix the issue.

```
window.onload = function(){
  const btns = document.querySelector('.song-details');
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp
Read more about onload event here

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<template>` element to organize your code better.

```html
<template id="songTemplate">
  <div class="song-details"> IDs
    <div class="song-num"></div>
    <div class="song-poster"><img alt=""></div>
    <div class="song-artist-name">
      <div class="song-name"></div>
      <div class="artist-name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play-btn"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
      play_arrow
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then, you can easily access all the elements through query selectors.

```js
const template = document.getElementById("songTemplate");
for (let song of goodVibesPlaylist) {
  const content = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  content.querySelector('.song-details').id = song.idd;
  content.querySelector('.song-num').textContent = song.idd;
  content.querySelector('.song-poster > img').src = song.img;
  content.querySelector('.song-name').textContent = song.songName;
  content.querySelector('.artist-name').textContent = 'N' + song.artist;
  console.log(content.firstElementChild.id);
  document.querySelector('#addTo').append(content);
}
```